# Transform image using only 4 points in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have `DisplayObject` where `width=600px, height=600px, x=0, y=0`. (X and Y begin in the left upper corner.) I know only 4 points' coordinates. For example, these coordinates are (100,100) (100,-100) (300,500) (300,-500.)

I'd like to transform this into `DisplayObject` where the four coordinates are: `(100,100) (100,-100) (300,500) (300,-500)`.

As you can see this transform is complicated. I can't perform this using only "width", "height". How can I do it using AS3?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't really get what you want.

Comment: I have DisplayObject with width=600px,height=600px,x=0,y=0(left upper corner). I'd like to transform this into Display object which have four coordinates
(100,100) (100,-100) (300,500) (300,-500)
How can I do it using AS3

Comment: What do the four points represent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the coordinates you mentioned, it sounds like you're trying to stretch a rectangular image into a trapezoid. I've never used this image distortion class, but it sounds like it could help:

http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use flash.geom.Matrix:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/